# I can not copy the Windows 98 folder to another drive in FreeDOS

Tags: hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, windows-98, freedos

Maybe you have read my other post about trying to install Windows 98 on modern hardware, hasn't come with much luck yet but i will never give up. So i ran into the problem about Win98 not knowing which drive to read from. So someone gave me a tip about copying all the Win98 files to the harddrive and running the installer from there. I do this in FreeDOS and the Win98 folder i have is made by copying all of the files from a Win98 ISO into a folder which i then put on a USB stick. But the problem comes when i try and copy the Win98 folder from my USB stick to the harddrive of the computer. It doesn't seem to want to copy it to the hard drive. I try to do the ''xcopy e: d:'' command but it doesn't work. Note: I run FreeDOS off of a separate USB stick and the Win98 folder is on another stick. Does anyone know what the problem is? Or am i doing it wrong?

Comment: This should be posted in the Retrocomputing site of Stack Exchange

Comment: Boot into windows (or Linux).  Copy the win98 setup folder (and anything else you want) to your ALREADY BOOT READY FreeDos USB stick from there.  Boot off of the USB stick.  Start installation.  Am I understanding the problem correctly?

Comment: Partly yes, but i have a problem that prevents me from doing that i am pretty sure, the installer has some trouble if i run it off the USB.